# In MongoDB is there a performance difference when including indexes and non-indexed values in a filter?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

If we have a model like

```
{
  typeIndex: number
  value: string
}
```

Are either of these more performant than the other?

```
const docs1 = await Model.find({ typeIndex: 1, value: regexpstring })
const docs2 = await Model.aggregate([
  { $match: { typeIndex: 1 } },
  { $match: { value: regexpstring} }
])
```

My hunch is to use the first one. Will it actually scan only indexes first and then the `value`, or because it sees `value` it will immediately go to document scanning?

Comment: base on the [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/indexes/), yeah, it does have different. without index, MongoDB must perform a collection scan first.

Comment: They both have indexes. But I already used `explain()` and it's parsed into one `$and` in both cases anyway. Idk if this is mongoose or mongodb.

Comment: i am bit confused about your 2nd query, actually it can be in a single $match => `{ $match: { typeIndex: 1, value: regexpstring } }`

Comment: anyway, if both are indexes already, there will be no different in my opinion. but index is used to find the one key, so if you find both in the same time, i think its useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MongoDB query planner will combine the two match stages into one, so those queries are equivalent.

If there is an index on `typeIndex`, it will be used in both cases.  If that index also includes `value` the index can support that predicate if the regular expression is anchored to the beginning of the string.